# Dynamic variables in Twigs

Tags: symfony, twig

In a form, I dynamically define the fields in a controller. Then in the `TWIG` I would like to use `form_widget` to output the fields.

The normal approach, when knowing the fields is like shown bellow:

```
{{ form_widget(form.field1) }}
```

In this case, we cannot know whether we will have a `field1`, `field2`, etc. on beforehand. Though we have the field names in a variable called `key`.

So what we would like to achieve is replace the hardcoded `field1` by something dynamic.

Comment: Do you have to type in the field names? You could just render the whole form  `{{ form_start(form) }}
                {{ form_errors(form) }}
                {{ form_label(form) }}
                {{ form_widget(form) }}
                {{ form_end(form) }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```
{{ form_widget(form[key]) }}
```